# XPages - modify display of Dojo Time Text box

Tags: dojo, xpages, lotus-notes

I'm using a Dojo Time Text Box on my XPage. When I save a time in this field, the displayed time has a "T" prefix. Is there any way of removing this "T"? Here is my code:

```
<xp:inputText id="EventEndTime" value="#{document1.EventEndTime}"         style="width:160px;"
role="button" title="used to pick a meeting time" required="true"
dojoType="dijit.form.TimeTextBox"
disableClientSideValidation="true">
<xp:this.dojoAttributes>
<xp:dojoAttribute    name="required"  value="false">
</xp:dojoAttribute>                           
</xp:this.dojoAttributes>                                
</xp:inputText>
```

Comment: Please read here: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/form/TimeTextBox.html They mentioned why the T but said that when you get the value programmatically the return value will be native javascript date object.

Comment: Thanks, I have read this but I'm afraid that I'm still not sure what I need to do to change the display of the field's value.

Comment: I am bit lost as to where are you getting the value from and where you are saving it? Please clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a custom converter to your inputText control which deletes the "T" before saving and adds "T" during rendering page:

```xml
<xp:this.converter>
    <xp:customConverter>
        <xp:this.getAsObject><![CDATA[#{javascript:value.substring(1)}]]></xp:this.getAsObject>
        <xp:this.getAsString><![CDATA[#{javascript:"T" + value}]]></xp:this.getAsString>
    </xp:customConverter>
</xp:this.converter>
```

This way time gets saved as string like "hh:mm:ss" instead of "Thh:mm:ss".

You could use a custom converter to save value as a Notes time value also.

Comment: Be aware: when you save this back into a DateTime Notes item, you might not get the clean time back. Storing into a TextItem will work in any case.

Comment: @stwissel: my example code above stores the time as Text item. I added my last sentence to give an idea what customConverter can be used for too. You're right that DateTime Notes item is more complicated to use but might handle local time e.g.

Comment: The converter approach is simple and elegant - love it

Answer (score 3):

Domino doesn't actually store "Time only", so you would want to use a viewScope variable to bind to your TimeTextBox first and use the load and save events to write to / read from that. I would use the [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class for conversion which is way more comfortable that manual string operations. Actually a small Java helper class works wonders here.

Alternatively you could use a filter to clean this up.